# Cross platform application implementation design

Tags: c++

I have a project with multiple classes (a few global). Now I have decided to support another embedded platform than the one I already run on. My question is how to run certain parts of code depending on which platform I'm running on. I have a way to detect which platform it is at the start of the program. Should I use a global variable, and check it everywhere I want to run specific code. Eg.

```
if (platform_A)
    // code here
else if (platform_B)
    // code here
```

This looks a bit ugly, and sprinkling this check everywhere on the app seems not ideal. I will also have to use different file paths for the different platforms. For that one I may declare global file path variables and define them in runtime based on the platform it's running on.

Is there a general guide/structure/design for writing such an application efficiently?

Comment: read about dependency injection. It is great method to hide platform specific stuff behind abstraction.

Comment: I recommend using [QFileSelector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileselector.html) for things like loading different resources on different platforms.

Comment: @MarekR will do, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JarMan I am familiar with that. This next platform that I'm looking to support will actually be running without a GUI, so no QML files will be involved. Thanks for the suggestion though, seems that it will be useful for like file paths, I hadn't considered it.

Comment: QQmlFileSelector is for QML files, but QFileSelector is for other files.

Comment: @JarMan right, I just learned that!